# Undo manage webmvc-config.xml Can't get Type details

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, roo, gvnix

Tried to use gvNIX to create datatables for my domain model. Followed the [quickstart](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-app) on github, with modifications for my problem domain. Everything runs OK until I get to:

```
~.domain.Profile roo-gvNIX> web mvc datatables add --type ~.web.Profile --inline true --ajax true
```

Which results in:

```
Undo manage SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml
Can't get Type details
```

What is the meaning of the "Undo manage" message? Anything else I can investigate?

Comment: Opened a bug in github: https://github.com/gvSIGAssociation/gvnix/issues/20

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that expected **--type** should be a controller. In the example above:

```
web mvc datatables add --type ~.web.ProfileController --inline true --ajax true
```

instead of:

```
web mvc datatables add --type ~.web.Profile --inline true --ajax true
```